# Link two entities based on unique value not ID

Tags: nhibernate, domain-driven-design

I have the following database tables. Primary keys are ID and AnimalType.Type is a unique string.

```
Animal
- ID
- Name
- TypeID

AnimalType
- ID 
- Type [Herbivore, Carnivore]
```

My classes are as follows.

```
public class Animal
{
    public int ID { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public AnimalType Type { get; set; }
}

public class AnimalType
{
    private int ID { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

How would I get the following code to work in NHibernate so that it references the same AnimalType of **Herbivore**?

```
var horse = new Animal() { Name = "Horse", Type = new AnimalType() { "Herbivore" }};

repository.SaveOrUpdate(horse);

var rabbit = new Animal() { Name = "Rabbit", Type = new AnimalType() { "Herbivore" } };

repository.SaveOrUpdate(rabbit);
```

**UPDATE**

Be nice if I could get NHibernate to perform this logic: http://andreas.scherbaum.la/blog/archives/11-Avoid-Unique-Key-violation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd investigate a few options.

1) If the data doesn't change frequently, can you make AnimalType an Enum instead of an Entity Object?

2) Instantiate an object of the Herbivore AnimalType using `animalTypeRepository.FindByType("Herbivore")` and pass that object into your new Animal.

3) Move the above logic into the `animalRepository.SaveOrUpdate(animal)` method so that you'd have...

```
public class AnimalRepository
{
  public void SaveOrUpdate(Animal animal)
  {
    var animalType = animal.Type;
    if (animalType.ID == 0)
    {
      animal.Type = animalTypeRepository.Find(animalType.Type);
    }

    // save or update animal...
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the way I assumed it would be done, my question specifically is around support within NHibernate for this scenario.

Comment: You could investigate the usage of the property-ref attribute on the many-to-one tag within the Animal mapping. This allows you to reference another table by a non-FK column. Although if the data isn't going to change, then you are far better to use an enum.